# How to check orientation of interface prior to viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a LoginViewController that you can navigate back and forth from the MainMenuViewController. I am adjusting subviews' positioning and size programmatically using **willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation**

This works great. The problem I am having is that I need to check the orientation right when the ViewController is loaded, in case it is loaded and you are in landscape orientation, the same changes I make in **willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation** will be made.

The problem is, the earliest point I can get **self.interfaceOrientation** is in the viewDidAppear method, and this causes the user to see the original sized/positioned subviews for a split second before it transitions to the landscape-appropriate sizes/positions. I tried in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear and neither of these work because (what I believe), self.interfaceOrientation is still NULL at this moment. How can I work around this and get the changes to be made prior to the user viewing the page (viewDidAppear)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What about `viewWillApear` method ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are looking for this method :

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews 
{

}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html

"The viewWillLayoutSubviews method is also called after the view is resized and positioned by its parent."

Comment: When i call a method to check self.interfaceOrientation and based on what is returned, I make changes to labels, imageviews, textfields, etc. At the time of viewWillAppear, self.interfaceOrientation is NULL

Comment: Sorry - let me re-phrase. When my iPad is laying down flat on the table, it shows my storyboards landscape orientation but still self.interfaceOrientation still returns as portrait

Comment: have you tried the `-viewWillLayoutSubviews` 
since the link in my answer is kinda similar to ur question it should work

Comment: I just tried it. It works well up until the point when I segue away from a View Controller and then back to it, the resizing of the subviews happens twice..so it's size which was initially set to size * 0.9 the second time around does it twice and is out of position

Comment: Also I think it is for another question here :-/

Comment: So my suggestion is to have some `BOOL` to recognise the orientation in `viewWillLayoutSubviewa`, and change the Layouts some where else , maybe in `viewDidLoad`
or in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Not working - it gets to the method that alters the different views, but the changing of the frames does nothing